# Best tool to BruteForcing RDP

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, rdp

I have tried many tools and to do not seem to be successful with locking out an account I am testing on my network with an RDP domain. I used crowbar, ncrack and THC hydra but they don't seem to be working accurately. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to approach this for testing?

Comment: is the RDP account set up to lock out after a certain number of attempts?

Comment: @schroeder yep, they lockout after 5 attempts.

Comment: have you tried by hand to ensure your end-to-end process is working correctly?

Comment: @schroeder I will have my admins try that. If that does not work what would be the next step?

Comment: If 3 tools do not work, I think you need to start troubleshooting the process, not the tools. Hydra is the gold standard for this task. Either the target, the network, or the common way that you are using all 3 tools should be looked at

Comment: @schroeder Good point, I did see that the THC hydra rdp module is currently having issues from what users are reporting.

Comment: @schroeder Would Hydra tell me if a firewall is blocking the attempts? I have tried crowbar,ncrack and hydra still no luck. It is locking out when i manually hand jamming it but the tools I use are not locking it out. So weird..

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with hydra and ncrack, I might suggest trying Patator, but really you want to troubleshoot what is going on.

For a thorough check that also involves an additional layer of testing, try — https://github.com/SySS-Research/Seth